# Eclipse reports gradle error when I'm using only maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle

I have a maven project (with git control) like below structure

```
project-parent
   pom.xml
-- sub_proj_a
   pom.xml
   ...
-- sub_proj_b
   pom.xml
   ...
```

It works no problem when executing maven commands such as compile, install in console.
But it always shows error like below in eclipse

| Description | Resource | Path | Location | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Missing Gradle project configuration file: .settings/org.eclipse.buildship.core.prefs | project-parent |  | Unknown | Gradle Project Configuration Marker |

I have no idea why gradle is triggered.
I do have gradle projects in my eclipse, but the problem is there still even I closed all other projects.
BTW, my Eclipse IDE version:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2022-03 (4.23.0)

The .project file is like (it should be created by Eclipse automatically when I import the project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
        <name>project-parent</name>
        <comment>Project project-parent created by Buildship.</comment>
        <projects>
        </projects>
        <buildSpec>
                <buildCommand>
                        <name>org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleprojectbuilder</name>
                        <arguments>
                        </arguments>
                </buildCommand>
                <buildCommand>
                        <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
                        <arguments>
                        </arguments>
                </buildCommand>
        </buildSpec>
        <natures>
                <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
                <nature>org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleprojectnature</nature>
        </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: Do you have .settings in git?

Comment: Please show your `.project` file.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen How can the problem be caused by missing of sharing the `.settings` folder?

Comment: @howlger or any other eclipse project file.  My guess is that a colleague has this plugin.  Was the .project file the one that could be shared between users?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The `.project` and `.classpath` files and the `.settings` folder have to be shared. This is why Eclipse puts these files into the project folder and not into the `.metadata` outside of the project folder.

Comment: @howlger As you probably know, you do normally not _need_ to share IDE specific configuration files for Maven projects.   My money is still on the colleague using Groovy.

Comment: No. I have no .settings/ in git. I ignore it by .gitignore.

Comment: @JieHuang Double check, you might have an old copy from before the .gitignore file was modified

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Again, the `.project` and `.classpath` files and the `.settings` folder are intended to be shared. Eclipse puts these files into the project folder. No developer of an IDE questions this. Misinformation about this is only spread by people who don't know what the files in `.settings` are for.

Comment: Your issue is caused by the `.project` file, not by `.settings/*` files (not sharing those files is a different problem). According to the comment element in `.project`, the `.project` file has been created by [Buildship](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship). It looks like you imported your project as Gradle project by mistake. Does replacing the `.project` and `.classpath` files and the `.settings` folder files and adapting the name in `.project` from a working project of the same kind fix your issue? Please make sure to share those files to avoid such issues in future.